# Controlling draft options from a Makefile

Tags: draft, makefile

I would like to control class options such as `draft` and geometry package's `showframe` from a Makefile.  Is there a way I can parameterise a document using LaTeX itself, or will I need to preprocess the document using sed from the Makefile?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is something I use quite often.

In your document you do this:

```
\providecommand\classopts{}
\expandafter\documentclass\expandafter[\classopts]{article}
```

The `\expandafter` shouldn't be necessary, however, I always provide them.

The `\providecommand` only adds the command if it didn't already exist. So you just need to create the command beforehand and then you can switch between different schemes.

In your makefile you can then do:

```
draft:
    pdflatex "\def\classopts{draft}\input{document}"
pdf:
    pdflatex document
```

And then you have two different compilations, one with draft and the other with regular settings.

I typically use it for switching between compiling handouts and the presentation for a `beamer` presentation.

Comment: This works great!  I've used `pdflatex "\def\classopts{,draft}\input{document}"` (note the leading comma) so that I can append options to a list of standard class options such as `a4paper`

Comment: It works nice for me too. It has, however, a drawback: Since you call the main document with `\input{document}` from the command line it is not possible to input (or include) other files from there. This is a nice feature for large documents. The reason why this is not longer possible is that `\input` cannot be nested.

Comment: @fborchers you can nest as many `\input` as you want (basically), See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301456/what-is-the-maximum-nesting-depth-of-input)

Comment: @fborchers, you might have been thinking of the `\include` command which cannot be nested. https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=20341