# Always creating a second document with slightly different configuration

Tags: tex-core, compiling

I work on a document, and I would like to create, simultaneously, another document which has the 'doublespacing' tag on. Until now, every time I needed it, I just copied the TEX file to a "file-name-doublespace.tex", put on the `doublespacing` tag, and recompile.

Is there a way to automate this, so that on each compilation of the single file, I will get two files: `original.pdf` and `original-doublespace.pdf` which has the `\doublespacing` command?

Thanks.

Comment: Would something like this help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169070/controlling-draft-options-from-a-makefile/169079#169079

Comment: Yes, thank you. I just needed to add also ``job-name`` in PDFlatex to produce the different file name.

Comment: yes. That is of course required (or you can let the make command move the files). I will mark it as a duplicate.