# Produce two outputs in Vim-LaTeX compilation

Tags: vim, vim-latex

I would like to make ViMLaTeX compilation to produce two outputs - let's say, one with the `draft` option in the `documentclass` command. Or even better - to have two different ViM commands, one for normal compilation (`\ll` etc.) and one for a `draft` compilation.

Appreciate any assistance,

Comment: Assuming that the answer to [your previous question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/214054) works correctly, isn't this just a question about making a vim command to run `make draft` or `make pdf` in the shell?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to control the latex commands vimlatex uses. for instance, for can I get the 'source' for the `\ll` command and edit it?

Comment: I don't use vim, but I suspect [Vim documentation: Customizing Latex-Suite](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/customizing-compiling.html) would be a start. Or you could run `make` inside vim with `:make`, and I assume that will take a `pdf` or `draft` argument for your previous Makefile. But this is still really a vim question, not a LaTeX one.